# Opening any Windows 10 UWP Project gives error for all "await" statements

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, uwp, windows-10-universal

I updated Visual Studio Community 2015 to Update 3 and since then, all "await" statements in UWP apps are throwing errors.

The errors I receive are -

> The type 'IAsyncAction' is defined in an assembly that is not
>   referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Windows,
>   Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null,
>
> The type 'IAsyncActionWithProgress<>' is defined in an assembly that
>   is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Windows,
>   Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null,
>
> The type 'IAsyncOperation<>' is defined in an assembly that is not
>   referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Windows,
>   Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null,
>
> The type 'IAsyncOperationWithProgress<>' is defined in an assembly
>   that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Windows,
>   Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null,

For now, this is all that I have tried to - Clean install Visual Studio Community 2015 Update 3 along with UWP Tools 1.4, SDK 10586 and SDK 10240; manually reinstalling each SDK.

Comment: Probably related : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/efd8c188-1b30-4154-b3da-b3954194b894/uapuwp-cs0012-error-after-installing-vs-2015-update-1-on-10586?forum=wpdevelop

Comment: I have already tried that...But it hasnt worked. Anyways, thanks for the quick reply.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this error in the past too when I upgraded from VS version 1 to 2 I think, seem like this error was caused by me trying to upgrade instead of doing a clean install, I fixed it by removing VS and anything related to it from the control panel, then did a clean install and it was fixed.

Comment: So did I, the SDK installer is pretty miserable.  It builds Windows.winmd dynamically at install time and that procedure is quite brittle.  A clean install did not fix it, oh joy.  After two days of slugging it out, I finally discovered that one contract file was missing.

Comment: So what should I try to do? I have already tried clean install.

Answer (score 1):

I uninstalled both SDKs manually and reinstalled them. The problem seems to be fixed lol.